# Upgrade to 3.0.0 RC1 failed due to 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: craft3, upgrades, timeout

I got a notification in the Craft 3 beta versions I have been working on to upgrade to 3.0.0 RC1. I clicked update and it began updating only the throw the following error. Any ideas what may have happened?

```
Status: Gateway Time-out

Response: <html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.12.2</center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

If it's of any help, this is a composer install using Valet to run.

Comment: I manage to solve the issue by using composer to upgrade, but first had to delete the composer lock file.

Answer (score 2):

Updated using `composer update craftcms/cms`

Comment: I tried this and was getting: Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: craftcms/server-check[1.1.0, 1.0.17]. So I needed to just run `composer update` to update dependencies too. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this article to help debug 504 Gateway Timeout errors that can be common when updating Craft, because those tend to be longer running operations: https://craftcms.com/support/504-gateway-timed-out-error

[Your solution](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/23093/57) works because PHP timeouts from the command line are generally much more forgiving that PHP timeouts from a web browser.

Craft 3 uses [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) for its updating needs (for itself and for plugins).  Composer has a tendency to be the opposite of fast, so you might want to go ahead and bump things like your php.ini file's `max_execution_time` for future updates if you plan on doing it from the Control Panel.